# Floating Bar Chart for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, charts

Anyone knows a chart API to make Floating Bar Chart in Qt/C++?

Example of floating Bar Chart in JavaScript is here:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/floating-bar-chart/

Comment: google `qwt`. It's probably the best and easiest-to-use plotting framework for Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com). It can do floating bar chart and can work with Qt.